# ggplot: change the order of stacked bars based on the % component of a level within the bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have created a stacked bar plot in `ggplot` as such:

```
antr1$Traits4<-factor(antr1$Traits4,
                      levels=c("Flight", "Avoidance", "Investigative",
                               "Defensive aggression","Active aggression"))

ggplot(antr1, aes(Receiver3, fill=Traits4)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill") + 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous("", formatter="percent") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Flight"="yellow",
                             "Avoidance"="green",
                             "Investigative"="blue",
                             "Defensive aggression"="orange",
                             "Active aggression"="red"))
```

It works nicely. However, at the moment the bars are ordered alphabetically based on the names of the "Receiver3". I would like to reorder the stacked bars based on the percentage of the level of "Active aggression".

thanking you in advance

Matt

Answer (score 3):

If you know the order of the levels of Receiver3 that you'd like, you can specify is via something like:

```
antr1$Receiver3 <- factor(antr1$Receiver3,
                    levels=c(...list the levels in the order you'd like...),
                    ordered=TRUE)
```

If Receiver3 has many levels so determining the correct order by hand is prohibitive, you might try something like this:

```
temp <- aggregate(antr1$Traits4,by=list(receiver=antr1$Receiver3),
          FUN=function(xx){
                return(sum(xx=='Active aggression')/length(xx))
          }
antr1$Receiver3 <- factor(antr1$Receiver3,levels=temp$receiver[order(temp$x)],
                     ordered=TRUE)
```

If you want to opposite order, change order(temp$x) to order(temp$x,decreasing=TRUE).